# Nut on back axle

Tags: rear-wheel, modification, cruiser, motor

I have a motor kit for my beach cruiser, but I can't take the brake lever off to install the sprocket on the left side of the axle. The wheel is off the bike, but I can't budge the nut holding the brake lever on. The sprocket needs to go behind it, and then brake lever back on.

Comment: Presumably you're referring to the rear wheel, and its the brake reaction arm for a coaster brake?   Normally "brake lever" would mean the ones on the handlebar.   Could you add a photo showing the area?  I suspect rust is threadlocking a bolt in place, or your wheel is possibly not compatible with your kit.

Answer (score 1):

The reaction arm (the thing you are calling a brake lever, which it is in some sense) will either be fitting over the wrench flats of the left side cone, or in some cases might be integrally joined with it.

One way of doing this is put the wheel back on the bike, fasten down the drive side axle nut and the reaction arm just like normal, leave the left side axle nut loose or off, and then slip a wrench from the back on to the locknut and pull up to unscrew it (normal loosening direction). This way you're using the frame as leverage.

To do it off the bike you typically need to find something to stick on the end of the reaction arm for additional leverage, like a pipe or the closed end of a suitably sized combination wrench (which is clumsy and floppy but it's what I usually do because it uses whatever's closest at hand).